# View vote on tags synonyms

Tags: feature-request, voting, tag-synonym-process

Since we hit 1,000 rep, we become the [Established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) and one of the feaures we can use is the view vote to see the ratio of down-votes and up-votes.

Unlike the case of voting on suggested synonyms, where is just a number. I have proposed a tag synonym and its current state is `pending (2)`, and after clicking on that tag, I see only the number **2** between two arrows the same like on questions/answers, but without possibility to see the ratio.

For me it's a bit difference to see the ratio:

- 2 up-votes vs 0 down-votes
- 18 up-votes vs 16 down-votes

Despite the count is same, the number of people participated varies.

Does it make sense to add this feature? In my opinion it does. I often wonder if the number remains same or if there is something hidden behind.

Comment: Why stop there? The synonym suggestion system [is broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127459/234299), we should [fix all the things!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204244/improving-tag-synonyms)